# Trying to access localhost over LAN on mobile device :404 Error

Tags: android, http-status-code-404, wamp, lan, ipod-touch

I'm trying to access my wampserver localhost through an Android device and iPod Touch over my LAN, and I keep getting a 404 error no matter what.  Here's what I'm getting from my apache server access log:

```
192.168.1.81 - - [26/Nov/2013:23:51:42 -0800] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 198
192.168.1.81 - - [26/Nov/2013:23:53:12 -0800] "GET /install.txt HTTP/1.1" 404 209
```

Comment: Are you sure both are in the same LAN?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the problem was that I hadn't added

192.168.1.81 to my hosts file

Comment: Since when should the server add clients to its hosts file?!!

Answer (score 0):

You'll get this error if you access /install.txt from the node of your webserver as well. The file doesn't exist or maybe is not readable by the webserver process. It has nothing to do with your iPod or Android device.

Open a browser on the machine of your webserver and try it.

Comment: I can access this file from my webserver.

Comment: Then you have a problem with your Apache configuration. Which URL do you enter in your iPod? Enter the same URL in your Browser on the webserver. Then you can show us the Apache log, but please edit your question since it is too hard to read as comment.